# Unwanted lag in plots in a R Shiny modal dialogue

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a R shiny app. One feature of the app is plots that appear in a modal dialogue.

The unwanted behaviour is that when the modal dialogue is launched the plot briefly shows the previously generated plot for a few seconds before updating to the new plot (assuming the inputs have changed).

I found that setting the `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` argument in the `outputOptions()` function removed the error but introduced a new unwanted behaviour: an "invalid quartz() device size" error briefly appears when the modal dialogue is first launched. This seems to be the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968338/invalid-quartz-device-size-when-suspendwhenhidden-is-added).

So I am seeking a solution to the "invalid quartz() device size" error or an alternative solution to the original problem!

The code below should reproduce the errors. In this example, the user can generate a random plot, either point, bar or line. If the user changes plot type the modal briefly shows the plot from the previously selected type before updating. The second problem can be illustrated by commenting in the line `outputOptions(output, "plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`. If this is included the lagging plot issue is fixed but there is the "invalid quartz() device size" error the first time the app is lauched.

Thank you for any pointers!

**app.R**

```
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons('type', "Choose plot type", c("point", "bar", "line")),
    actionButton("show", "Show random plot")

)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$show, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
            plotOutput('plot')
        ))
    })
    
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    shinipsum::random_ggplot(type = input$type)
})

# Adding this line fixes the issue but results in an invalid quartz() device size error
# outputOptions(output, "plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error does not occur if you set a width and a height in `renderPlot`:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    shinipsum::random_ggplot(type = input$type)
}, width = 400, height = 400)


outputOptions(output, "plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```